# Word/phrase/idiom for something which is no longer under technical development

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word which describes 'technically complete' in a single word.

An example usage of such a word in a phrase is: 'This product is now X but not yet commercialized'

Comment: I would probably use ***finalized*** for this, but I'd want a bit more context before giving that as an answer.

Comment: **production ready**

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - I used 'completed' (similar to finalized) before but it was deemed not specific enough by management. They suggested 'Technically completed' but i prefer a single word which conveys this meaning. The context is that we develop materials for customers and keep track of these materials in a database. When we have finished developing the material we want to set it to a certain status that it is clear that development has completed but the material has not been commercialized yet. This can be for a number of reasons, e.g. waiting on customer feedback on trial runs.

Comment: *ready to be commercialized* or *ready to be externalized*.

Comment: It seems like the jargon of the software industry to describe an almost-ready version as "the beta." Perhaps you could say that your product is "post-beta" or "out of beta"?

Comment: Chaim, *Beta* isn't jargon and doesn't mean *almost ready*.

FYI, *Alpha* products have passed in-house testing with but the designers accept that might be due as much to luck as judgement. Will it be jargon if the term is *First-stage certified*? Both are readily understood, clearly defined, technical terms.

Once graded *Alpha* the product goes to *Beta* testing: broadly, the designers have found no faults but they recognise laboratories are not real life.

Then what place remains for your *post…* or *out of beta*, please?

Comment: If Jeff's *finalised* doesn't, why would neither *complete* nor the familiar *finished* work for you, please? *The finished product…* is so well recognised, it's more a cliche than even an idiom.

Comment: It depends on whether it's really being pursued or not, and the impression the speaker wants to convey.  Often products are allowed to sit without producing/promoting them for a variety of good and bad reasons.

Comment: I feel like I've seen "graduated" used in a similar sense (perhaps analogous to professional students who have graduated but aren't yet licensed).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be **mature**:

> having attained a final or desired state

[Marriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mature)

Answer (score 0):

Validated, is usually what is used in Engineering assemblies, sub-assemblies as well as component level product. Once a component is validated it is used in the next upper level of the product which includes either or both sub-assemblies and assembly or finished goods.

Answer (score 0):

An idiom. as requested in title of question:

[done and dusted](https://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-alphalists/alpha-list_D/id_D7-doldrums-down.html)  When a project, task or activity is done and dusted, it is completely finished or ready.

As in:

> I've nearly finished preparing the presentation.  When it's all done
>   and dusted I'll be able to relax.

Answer (score 0):

Consider saying that the product is *ready*. Depending on the phrasing, it can refer to the technical completion (*ready but not commercialised*) or the anticipation of the next phase (*ready for commercialisation*).

> **ready** *adjective*
>   1.1 (of a thing) made suitable and available for immediate use.
>   ‘When the processes have finished, the oven bleeps and the product is ready for sale.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ready)

Answer (score 0):

Production ready? In software terms this illustrates ready for shipping to customers.